# paizaでローカルホストにアクセスできない

Tags: angular4

今、下記のソースを試してみようと思い、paizaでクラウドを借りて動かそうと試みています。
Angularをはじめ、必要なものをインストールしました。

https://github.com/MasaharuKomuro/internal-arbitrage/tree/master/src
このソースの解説は、こちらです。
https://qiita.com/hedrall/items/fa8d43292f6bbeaf96d7

依存関係は、


`$npm install`


を使って対応しました。
記事は、こちらを読みました。
http://phiary.me/node-js-package-manager-npm-usage/

paizaのクラウドのローカルのアドレスの形式に従いコマンドを入力すると、エラーになります。
[image: エラーの説明]

最初に掲載したアドレスの解説記事の通りに、ポートを指定して起動すると、successfullは出ますが、ブラウザでは、エラーになります。
ただ、ビルド？の結果の中で、ライブのところがNGになっています。
[image: 解説通りの結果]

[image: ブラウザの結果]

一応、ローカルのIPの127.0.0.1で指定しても、ダメでした。
paozaのローカルのアドレスの指定の方法が特有なようで、困っています。
どこかのファイルの中身を修正して直るなど、解決をご存知の人がみえましたら、ご教授頂けましたら幸いです。

Comment: エラーが発生する場合の入力コマンドを教えていただけますか？
また、ログはできるだけ全量を文字列で掲載していただけると良いです。

Comment: 入力したコマンドやエラーメッセージ等はあとで検索した人が辿り着きやすいためにも画像(だけ)でなく文字でも質問文に入れるようにしてください。

Comment: すみません。私も慌てていて肝心のInvalid Host headerのエラーメッセージを書き忘れてしまいました。気を付けます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デフォルトではWebpack dev serverがlocalhost以外からのアクセスを拒否する際の挙動のためのようです。

`ng serve`のかわりに `ng serve  --disable-host-check`でサーバーを起動できませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えてくださったコマンドを試したら、無事に表示できました。